# Continuously Subtracting value with some conditions

Tags: sql, process, conditional-statements, subtraction

```
Man.No     ProdNumber     Sequence   Code    Process1Time   Process2Time     Standard
 1330        01864       1        H3       113           43
 1330        01865       2        H3        97           39
 1330        01866       3        H1        72           41
 1330        01867       4                  56           39
 1330        01868       5        H3        50           39
 1330        01869       6        H1        43           41
 1330        01870       7                  39           40
 1331        01871       1        H2A       64           42
 1331        01872       2        H2A       56           41
 1331        01873       3        H2A       53           41
 1331        01874       4        H2A       49           39
 1331        01875       5        H2A       44           38
```

Hello everyone, this problem is stuck in my head in the past few weeks and i decide to ask now, this is not that simple for me. Im going to calculate the process standard time.

Here is the story, i did this one manually until now, the condition is :

Code start with H3 or A3, start time is 78
Other code or empty data, start time is 68

We calculate standard per Man.No, for example, at Man.No = 1330, sequence is from 1 until 7, for sequence number 7 at Man.No 1330, the code is blank, the standard will be **68** (FYI : The sequence number is varuious, it could be 7, 12, 8, or maybe 2, depends on the situation)

```
Man.No     ProdNumber     Sequence   Code    Process1Time   Process2Time   Standard
 1330        01864       1        H3       113           43
 1330        01865       2        H3        97           39
 1330        01866       3        H1        72           41
 1330        01867       4                  56           39
 1330        01868       5        H3        50           39
 1330        01869       6        H1        43           41
 1330        01870       7                  39           40             68
 1331        01871       1        H2A       64           42
 1331        01872       2        H2A       56           41
 1331        01873       3        H2A       53           41
 1331        01874       4        H2A       49           39
 1331        01875       5        H2A       44           38
```

After that, to calculate the sequence number 6 with H1 code which have to start with 68', we have to calculate it with this formula :
advance standard (68)+(45-(Average of Process2Time at current Man.No)) so it will be (68)+(45-((43+39+41+39+39+41+40)/7))) = 68+(45-40.3) = 68+4.7 = **72.7**

```
Man.No     ProdNumber     Sequence   Code    Process1Time   Process2Time     Standard
 1330        01864       1        H3       113           43
 1330        01865       2        H3        97           39
 1330        01866       3        H1        72           41
 1330        01867       4                  56           39                
 1330        01868       5        H3        50           39          
 1330        01869       6        H1        43           41           72.7
 1330        01870       7                  39           40           68
 1331        01871       1        H2A       64           42
 1331        01872       2        H2A       56           41
 1331        01873       3        H2A       53           41
 1331        01874       4        H2A       49           39
```

1331        01875       5        H2A       44           38

After that, to calculate the sequence number 5 with H3 code which have to start with 78' as i said before because it need more time (10') to process product, we have to calculate it with this formula : advance standard (72.7)+(45-(Average of Process2Time at current Man.No)**+10**). So it will be : (72.7)+(45-((43+39+41+39+39+41+40)/7)))**+10** = 72.7+(45-40.3)+10 = 72.7+4.7+10 = **87.4**

```
Man.No     ProdNumber     Sequence   Code    Process1Time   Process2Time   Standard
 1330        01864       1        H3       113           43
 1330        01865       2        H3        97           39
 1330        01866       3        H1        72           41
 1330        01867       4                  56           39                
 1330        01868       5        H3        50           39           87.4
 1330        01869       6        H1        43           41           72.7
 1330        01870       7                  39           40           68
 1331        01871       1        H2A       64           42
 1331        01872       2        H2A       56           41
 1331        01873       3        H2A       53           41
 1331        01874       4        H2A       49           39
 1331        01875       5        H2A       44           38
```

After that, to calculate the sequence number 4 with blank code which have to start with 68', we have to calculate it with this formula : advance standard (87.4)+(45-(Average of Process2Time at current Man.No)). So it will be : (87.4)+(45-((43+39+41+39+39+41+40)/7)))= 87.4+(45-40.3) = 87.4+4.7 = **92.1**

```
Man.No     ProdNumber     Sequence   Code    Process1Time   Process2Time   standard
 1330        01864       1        H3       113           43
 1330        01865       2        H3        97           39
 1330        01866       3        H1        72           41
 1330        01867       4                  56           39           92.1 
 1330        01868       5        H3        50           39           87.4
 1330        01869       6        H1        43           41           72.7
 1330        01870       7                  39           40           68
 1331        01871       1        H2A       64           42
 1331        01872       2        H2A       56           41
 1331        01873       3        H2A       53           41
 1331        01874       4        H2A       49           39
 1331        01875       5        H2A       44           38
```

continue with sequence 3 with H1 code, so we just need to plus 4,7 which is 92.1+4.7 = **96.8**

```
Man.No     ProdNumber     Sequence   Code    Process1Time   Process2Time   Standard
 1330        01864       1        H3       113           43
 1330        01865       2        H3        97           39
 1330        01866       3        H1        72           41           96.8
 1330        01867       4                  56           39           92.1 
 1330        01868       5        H3        50           39           87.4
 1330        01869       6        H1        43           41           72.7
 1330        01870       7                  39           40           68
 1331        01871       1        H2A       64           42
 1331        01872       2        H2A       56           41
 1331        01873       3        H2A       53           41
 1331        01874       4        H2A       49           39
 1331        01875       5        H2A       44           38
```

after that continue with sequence no 2 with H3 Code, remember, need +10. so it will be 96.8+4.7+10 = **111.5**

```
Man.No     ProdNumber     Sequence   Code    Process1Time   Process2Time   Standard
 1330        01864       1        H3       113           43
 1330        01865       2        H3        97           39           111.5
 1330        01866       3        H1        72           41          96.8
 1330        01867       4                  56           39          92.1 
 1330        01868       5        H3        50           39          87.4
 1330        01869       6        H1        43           41          72.7
 1330        01870       7                  39           40           68
 1331        01871       1        H2A       64           42
 1331        01872       2        H2A       56           41
 1331        01873       3        H2A       53           41
 1331        01874       4        H2A       49           39
 1331        01875       5        H2A       44           38
```

So finally we go to the first sequence, it will be not add +10 because the sequence 2 is also H3/A3 which need same time to process, so we just need to calculate, 111.5+4.7 = **116.2**

```
Man.No     ProdNumber     Sequence   Code    Process1Time   Process2Time   Standard
 1330        01864       1        H3       113           43           116.2
 1330        01865       2        H3        97           39           111.5
 1330        01866       3        H1        72           41           96.8
 1330        01867       4                  56           39           92.1 
 1330        01868       5        H3        50           39           87.4
 1330        01869       6        H1        43           41           72.7
 1330        01870       7                  39           40           68
 1331        01871       1        H2A       64           42
 1331        01872       2        H2A       56           41
 1331        01873       3        H2A       53           41
 1331        01874       4        H2A       49           39
 1331        01875       5        H2A       44           38
```

Thats all, its so horrible for me, thats why i would like to ask here, and if you think that i explain this matter too complicated, well i dont think so, because this is the simplest way to explain this horrible thing. will be so grateful if someone can help.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: I dont know how to, is there any link to make table for my question? i cant find it in the help section T_T

Comment: see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/246345

Answer (score 0):

So in order to do this in sql, first you need to come up with a formula for Standard that does not rely on the value of the standard for the next sequence. The first part is simple. If the Code is H3 or A3, you want 78, otherwise you want 68.

The next part of the formula in based on the average. You will want the average of all of the process1 times of the data with the same Man.No. As we move up the sequence, we are adding this average to the original value over and over again. Using your example, for sequence 6, we are adding the average once. For sequence 5, we are adding the average twice, for sequence 4, we add it 3 times. This becomes the average * (the max sequence # - the current sequence number). For the sequence 7, we will be adding the average on 0 times.

This is essentially the whole formula that you are using. Now, we can find these values using this formula in sql. Please note that this code is not tested and does not include your specific information since those details were not included in your question.

```
Select
    t.ManNum,
    t.ProdNum,
    t.Sequence,
    t.Code,
    t.Process1Time,
    t.Process2Time,
    (Select sum(Process1Time) / sum(1)
        From tabletbl t2
        Where t2.ManNum = t.ManNum
        Group by t2.ManNum)
    * ((Select max(Sequence)
         From tabletbl t2
         Where t2.ManNum = t.ManNum
         Group by t2.ManNum))-t.Sequence)
    + Case When (t.Code = H3 or t.Code = A3) Then 78 else 68 End
    as Standard
From tabletbl t
```